# Insert the content from worksheet adding some more text into another worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this VBA and got need help on how to fulfill my requirement. I have a excel sheet where i get the input from users using a userform. The data is stored on a sheet2. I need to use the contents of this sheet to create some text and then insert the newly created data into another sheet3 on specified cells.

For example, I have Fruit name and Fruit type on columns D2:E6 which i need to add to another sheet3 on cell C3

Contents from **Sheet2**

[image]

Content to be added on **Sheet3**

[image]

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

To copy some data with a specified range, you can just use following command in your module:

```
Sub copyData()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:D7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3")
End Sub
```

Also take a look at this site: https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another/